# Images in table

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm trying to view icons and text as a table, so the code looks like

**MyItemType.cs**

```
public class MyItemType
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Eliazar\Pictures\1556.bmp");
        b.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] ba = mstream.ToArray();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mstream);
        writer.Write(ba);

        MyItems = new List<MyItemType>();
        MyItemType newItem = new MyItemType();
        newItem.Image = ba;
        newItem.Title = "FooBar Icon";
        MyItems.Add(newItem);
        this.MainGrid.DataContext = this;
    }
    public List<MyItemType> MyItems { get; set; }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItemType}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}" Background="White" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,211.206,35,188.794">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

But nothing appears in the window. Does anybody have an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`Image.Source` needs to be of type `ImageSource` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx)). It does not know how to handle an array of bytes, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

agreed with Jens, `Image.Source` has to be of Type `ImageSource` (or `BitmapImage`)

You should do something like this:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Eliazar\Pictures\1556.bmp";

BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
source.EndInit();

newItem.Image = new Image() { Source = source };
```

Comment: @eliazar - don't forget to accept an answer if your problem is solved (either mine or Jens's)